# How do I get a list of files after an mput operation in ftp outbound gateway?

Tags: spring, ftp, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I manage to transfer file from local to remote ftp. Now, I want the list of paths and files that was involved so that I may apply logic on it like inserting new rows into the database. It was said that

> The message payload resulting from an mput operation is a List object (that is, a List of remote file paths resulting from the transfer).

which I get from [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/sftp.html#using-the-mput-command)

Here is my code, in which credited to Gary Russell for providing answer from my previous question

```
@Bean(value = "localToFtp")
public IntegrationFlow fileToFile() {
    IntegrationFlow flow = IntegrationFlows
            .fromSupplier(() -> "/local",
                    e -> e.poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(Duration.ofSeconds(5))))
            .handle(Sftp.outboundGateway(awasDelegatingSessionFactory(),
                    AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.Command.MPUT,
                    null)
                    .autoCreateDirectory(true)
                    .options(AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.Option.RECURSIVE)
                    .remoteDirectoryExpression(REMOTE_DIR))
            .channel("nullChannel")
            .get();
    return flow;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are discarding the list of file names returned by the gateway, by sending it to `nullChannel`.

Add another `.handle()` method there - the message payload is the list of remote paths.

Comment: Thank you again. I'm slowly understanding how DSL works

Comment: @Azinuddin How does the `REMOTE_DIR` looks like?